# GPU quota requested three times, support giving zero answers

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If I had known that google would outsource its customer help to stackexchange, i would have never signed up. Have tried adding a GPU to my quota in 2 regions, and finally tried adding it to global. Each time getting an email stating :

"We attempted to adjust the quota for your project: xxxx but
did not
find any changes that needed to be made."

I am still unable to request a GPU in any region, even when they are shown as having availability. when creating in instance it will not work either. At a loss here, and its unbelievable you cant get help as a paying customer without a titanium account or some nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

`GPU` / `TPU` can be requested in specific regions (only the quota may be global).

as unspecific as that question is, it is quite impossible to tell more ...

you're talking of "two regions", while not even telling which ones.

the [quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) should show, if resources are even available.

> When you request a GPU quota, you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones.

Comment: thanks for reply, yes billing is enabled btw. and i tried 2 different regions where the specific GPU i wanted was available (only tried global cause I have never had this issue before and thought it was related somehow thats all). not sure why the specific names would matter long as they had the GPU available. I have requested GPUs in the region before when using trial, now that i signed up, i no longer have GPU quota and the same method of procuring one is not working.

Comment: @JDOE the documentation reads "billing history" ~ which sounds alike "having paid at least one invoice, if not two or more"... because these GPU can be used to mine certain tokens, while the account could have been carded - therefore they might be rather cautiousness about that (that's at least how I'd interpret that).

Comment: Yeah, I know about miners, but the thing is, i got a GPU approved the day i signed up for the free trial.. now that ive used up all 300 hours, and i finally created a billing account as a bonafide customer.. NOW they make it difficult to get a GPU? also, the email i quoted makes no sense, it doesnt even mention whats going on at all. thanks again for reply.

Comment: and ive been downvoted to negative numbers. i wish people who downvoted on here without reasoning got banned.

Comment: @JDOE that down-vote was for "unclear what you are asking" ...which isn't that wrong, unless providing enough details to fully understand the issue, without having to ask for the details. see the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe i stated the question as well as the problem leading up to it just fine, when you asked for elaboration i merely restated what was already listed in the  original post, im sorry you had trouble understanding it yourself, but please do not downvote my thread because of your issue. thank you sir.